# How can I import a sqlserver database into Sharepoint

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sharepoint, database-connection

I have an SQL server data base, and i want to import the data into the Share point, i found a way that i could do it but i think it's not efficient, because i have to create a list manually for each table in the data base, if the data base has a 100 table, should i keep creating 100 lists 100 times for those tables ??, i need i way to import them from automatically, i mean without creating lists each time, is there a way for that?

NOTE: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=794 , this link show hoe to create list each time.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? If the data structure already is in a SQL Server it is usually recommended building external content types instead.

Comment: @EricHerlitz from 10 to 20 tables,and for 500 rows and could be more, i used the external contant typem but it let me create the tabelsl list by list each time, i want a way to do it one time, like really import the whole table from the database to the sharepoint from one time.

Answer (score 0):

The external content type route seems like the recommended route. If you have already created these there is a possibility you will be able to use some sort of powershell script to create the lists for you. I can't say i've ever used this but if it does what it says it should help you

[Scripting External content type lists](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/82437789-f294-4bcd-8210-a1ba0e081f82/)

Cheers
Truez